# IE11 insecure content warning show even there are all https request

Tags: internet-explorer

I am a web developer, our site is https://jianguoyun.com.
Recently the browser prompt insecure content warning while one of my colleagues visit our site using ie11 (It works well in my ie11 browser).
But we are using all https protocol in our site.
Anyone else encounter this situation? how do you fix this?

Comment: This seems better suited to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com webmasters or https://serverfault.com/ Server Fault...

Comment: well first time use stackvoerflow, thanks.

Comment: Open up the network tab and see what requests are being made.

Comment: all relative url, all HTTPS Protocol. maybe ie11 bug?